# Xamarin - Menu Hamburger Some ao clicar em botão voltar WP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Pessoal estou utilizando o código abaixo para criar um menu Master Detail em Xamarin.
O Código funciona perfeitamente em Android mas em Windows Phone ele tem um bug que não estou conseguindo resolver.

MainPage.cs

```
using AppNewsPlay.MenuItems;
using AppNewsPlay.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppNewsPlay
{
    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public List<MasterPageItem> menuList { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();


            // setando os icones e passando parametros para as paginas
            var page1 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Home", Icon = "ic_home_black_24dp.png", TargetType = typeof(Home) };
            var page2 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Xbox", Icon = "ic_dashboard_black_24dp.png", TargetType = typeof(Xbox) };
            var page3 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Playstation", Icon = "ic_games_black_24dp.png", TargetType = typeof(Playstation) };
            var page4 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Jogos", Icon = "ic_videogame_asset_black_24dp.png", TargetType = typeof(Jogos) };
            var page5 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Nintendo", Icon = "ic_phonelink_black_24dp.png", TargetType = typeof(Nintendo) };
            var page6 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Artigos", Icon = "ic_description_black_24dp.png", TargetType = typeof(Artigos) };
            var page7 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Sobre", Icon = "ic_info_black_24dp.png", TargetType = typeof(Sobre) };
            var page8 = new MasterPageItem() { Title = "Contato", Icon = "ic_perm_contact_calendar_black_24dp.png", TargetType = typeof(Contato) };

            //Adicionando Itens ao menu
            menuList.Add(page1);
            menuList.Add(page2);
            menuList.Add(page3);
            menuList.Add(page4);
            menuList.Add(page5);
            menuList.Add(page6);
            menuList.Add(page7);
            menuList.Add(page8);



            //Adicionando os itens ao ListView na MainPage.xaml
            navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;

            // Criando a Instancia da Pagina Inicial na Pagina Home
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Home))) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#000000"), BarTextColor = Color.White };


            // criando o bind para repassar a lista
            this.BindingContext = new
            {

                Header = "",
                Image = "novo_logo_40dpi_newsplay.png",
                // Rodape 
                Footer = ""


            };

            // desabilitando o indicador de carregamento
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            // ocultando a barra
            waitActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;

        }
        // função para o click do botão na lista
        private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
            Type page = item.TargetType;
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page)) { BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#000000"), BarTextColor = Color.White };
            IsPresented = false;

        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            base.OnBackButtonPressed();

            return true;

        }



    }
}
```

Quando eu clico em uma noticia e depois clico no **botão voltar** o Windows Phone simplesmente deixa de exibir o menu Hamburger, exibindo somente o conteudo da tela sem o menu,  sugestões de como resolver?

veja imagens

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para chamar a proxima tela eu uso o seguinte código.

```
   // Função que retorna o item selecionado da aba Ultimas Noticias
        private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
                    if(e.SelectedItem !=null)
                    {
                        var selection = e.SelectedItem as UltimasNoticias;
                        var PostView = new PostView(selection.Id);
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(PostView, true);
                        #region DisabledSelectionHighlighting
                        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
                        #endregion

                    }

        }
```

Comment: tenta remover base.OnBackButtonPressed(); do override que fez.

Comment: tenta definir o isVisible =  true do menu  quando  clicar no  botão de voltar

Answer (score 1):

Tive este problema ainda a pouco. Resolvi de uma maneira fácil no meu projeto. Vá ate a sua `MainPage.xaml` e adicione na tag `MasterDetailPage`:

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

O que acontece é que seu projeto esta com 2 `statusbar`, um precisa estar oculto.

Comment: valeu pela dica! ate hoje não resolvi isso kkkk

Comment: mesmo com isso não resolveu ?